# How to open with urllib, link parsed by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I use python 3, Beautiful Soup 4 and urllib for parsing some html.
I need to parse some pages, get some links from this pages, and than parse pages from that links. I try to do it like that:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/mypage?myparam=%D0%BC%D0%B2") as response:
    html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
total = soup.find(attrs={"class":"item_total"})
link = u"https://example.com" + total.find('a').get('href')
with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as response:
    exthtml = BeautifulSoup(html,response.read())
```

But urllib can't open second link, because it is not encoded, like fist link. It has different languages symbols, and white spaces.
I try to encode url, like:

```
link = urllib.parse.quote("https://example.com" + total.find('a').get('href'))
```

But it encode all symbols. How can I get properly url form bs, and get request?

UPD:
exapmle of second link, resulted by

```
link = u"https://example.com" + total.find('a').get('href')
```

is

```
"https://example.com/mypage?p1url=www.example.net%2Fthatpage%2F01234&text=абвгд еёжз ийклмно"
```

Answer (score 0):

should just be urlencoding your link.

`link = "https://example.com" + urllib.parse.quote(total.find('a').get('href'))`

Comment: That's may be work with python2, but this is python3 and thay gives me an error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. And actually urllib.parse.urlunparse doesn't workes too.

Comment: That's doesn't work too. See the example of link. urllib.parse.quote encode %2F symbols too, but they shouldn't. Firefox parse this link as well.